# How to get FFT Data in Swift using EZAudio?

Tags: ios, swift, fft, ezaudio

I am working on a fft analysis in swift with ezaudio.

My problem is how can i get the all fft data from ezaudio.

I would make a algorithm to look is a frequency present when yes how much strong.

Example:

I looking in the FFT Data is the Frequency 2000Hz present, is this Frequency present how much energy it have.

Here my code:

```
import UIKit
import Accelerate

class ViewController: UIViewController, EZMicrophoneDelegate,     EZAudioFFTDelegate{

private let ViewControllerFFTWindowSize: vDSP_Length = 4096

var microphone: EZMicrophone!
var fft: EZAudioFFTRolling!

override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()

    //setup audio session
    let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do{
        try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
        try session.setActive(true)
    }catch{
        print("Audio Session setup Fails")
    }

    microphone = EZMicrophone(delegate: self, startsImmediately: true)
    fft = EZAudioFFTRolling(windowSize: ViewControllerFFTWindowSize, sampleRate: Float(microphone.audioStreamBasicDescription().mSampleRate), delegate: self)

    microphone.startFetchingAudio()
}

func microphone(microphone: EZMicrophone!, hasAudioReceived buffer: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>>, withBufferSize bufferSize: UInt32, withNumberOfChannels numberOfChannels: UInt32) {

    fft.computeFFTWithBuffer(buffer[0], withBufferSize: bufferSize)

}

func fft(fft: EZAudioFFT!, updatedWithFFTData fftData: UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>, bufferSize: vDSP_Length) {
    var maxF = fft.fftData

    print(maxF)

    var data = fft.fftData
    print(data)

    //here coming my algorithm


}


}
```

With this code its giving a strange output on console:

```
var data = fft.fftData
print(data)
```

Output: 0x00000001119be000

Many Many thanks for help

Comment: Aren't you looking for `fft.maxFrequency` instead of `fft.fftData`?

Comment: no i want not only looking for the max frequency. i want looking for multiple frequency with a high energy. can you help me?

Comment: My question is only, how can i ged the fft data not how can i analyses this.

Comment: The docs say yes (http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/EZAudio/1.1.2/Classes/EZAudioFFT.html#//api/name/fftData), but when i print this to the console is the output  0x00000001119be000. I don't understand how can i get the float array data. Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 4):

`fftData` is an `UnsafeMutablePointer`, which is the Swift equivalent of a C pointer. A pointer is a memory address, not an actual value (hence the name: it *points* to memory, but isn't the memory itself).

So, when you print it, you get an address (`0x00000001119be000`). If you want to read the actual value of the memory at that address, you have to look it up. For example, to see the value (in this case a `Float`) at index 0, you can...

```
print(fftData[0])
```

To see all the values, just loop through and print them individually...

```
for (var i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++) {
   print(fftData[i])
}
```

`UnsafeMutablePointer` also has a property called `memory`...

```
print(fftData.memory)
```

but it will only return the value at that exact memory address, as opposed to the range of values you are interested in, making it equal to `fftData[0]`